# add acf filed to admin_menu programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress

can we add ACF fields to custom admin_menu page?
so I have created an admin page as shown

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'opt_add_admin_menu' );


function opt_add_admin_menu(  ) { 

    add_menu_page( 'opt', 'opt', 'manage_options', 'opt', 'opt_options_page' );

}
```

so next I need to add an ACF field to this options page
I got this code from ACF but the location still makes a problem for me

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):

acf_add_local_field_group(array(
    'key' => 'group_6335ef4ab316e',
    'title' => 'justfortest',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_6335ef5351c1c',
            'label' => 'text',
            'name' => 'text',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'maxlength' => '',
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'post_type',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'post',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
    'position' => 'normal',
    'style' => 'default',
    'label_placement' => 'top',
    'instruction_placement' => 'label',
    'hide_on_screen' => '',
    'active' => true,
    'description' => '',
));

endif;
```

```
'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'post_type', /* here we need to target the menu options page */
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'post', /* here to */
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

I know how to add fields programmatically without ACF but if there is a way to add through ACF it will be so helpful

Answer (score 0):

Create new admin page using acf option page

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
    
    acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'opt',
        'menu_title'    => 'opt',
        'menu_slug'     => 'opt-general-settings',
        'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
        'redirect'      => false
    ));
    
}
```

and select option page ->opt while adding new group

--- You need acf pro version to use this feature

Comment: i know that but if there is a way to use it within admin_menu cuz i need to include some options fields on my plugin